# How to create a View extension function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, extension-methods, kotlin-extension

I'm trying to create an extension function in Kotlin. I did try several tutorials, but didn't quite understand, how to implement this one.

I'm trying to create a `setWidth()` function as such

```
//Find my_view in the fragment
val myView = v.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.my_view)

//Then use the extension function
myView.setNewWidth(500)
```

This is how I've defined my extension function

```
private fun View?.setNewWidth(i: Int) {
    val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = View.layoutParams
    layoutParams.width = i
    View.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

I don't understand what I need to do here.

I want to call the extension function as `myView.ExtensionFunction()`, but I don't know how to do that. The tutorials, were un-informative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main problem here is how the extension function is defined, in particular, the lines that have `View.layoutParams` - this is calling a static property on `View` that doesn't exist. You need to use the one from the instance. If you'd write the extension function like so:

```
private fun View?.setNewWidth(i: Int) {
  val layoutParams = this?.layoutParams
  layoutParams?.width = i
  this?.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

Then you can call the method like you want. Personally, I don't find this so readable and I'd remove the nullability here and write it as:

```
private fun View.setNewWidth(i: Int) {
  val newLayoutParams = layoutParams
  newLayoutParams?.width = i
  layoutParams = newLayoutParams
}
```

The only difference is that now you need `?.` to call the method if the view is nullable, which I personally find fine - `myView?.setNewWidth(123)`. I assume most of the time you won't have a nullable view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So my issue was that I didn't know how to get reference to the calling View. i.e., I didn't know how to call `myView` and set its property inside the extension function `setNewWidth()`

So, I tried using `this?` and it worked.

Then, I did a few changes to the extension function to work for `myView` which is a `Relative Layout`.

This is what I worked out:

```
private fun RelativeLayout?.setWidth(i: Int) {
    val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams? = this?.layoutParams
    layoutParams?.width = i
    this?.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

Comment: It is `this` you use, not `this?`. E.g. you can't write `val view = this?`. `?` here is part of the `?.` safe call operator.